# Casting NULL to long is not ambigious?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying out an example for the usages of NULL vs nullptr.
As NULL can be casted into integral types, it should show ambiguity with the below example, but it isn't !!

It shows ambiguous candidate compile error, if it is unsigned long, but not for signed long.

Could anyone care to explain why !!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// NOTE: 
// "long" or "signed long" is not showing ambiguous candidates
// but "unsigned long" does

void func(long st) {
    cout << "overload func\n";
}

void func(int* ptr) {
    cout << "integer pointer overload func\n";
}

int main() {
    func(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on compiler, `NULL` might be declared as simple `0` or it might be declared as `(void*)0`.

Comment: and this is my you should use `nullptr`

Comment: Look at the definition of your `NULL` and you will deduce an answer on your question.

Comment: @GradyPlayer : yes, no warning, executes straight off fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Actually, I was waiting that you would comment. It shows me compile error for everything else, like int, float, double, short int, char, bool, unsigned char, signed char, unsigned long int... only except for the long. Is there a range of something involved.

Comment: Doesn't compile for one of my tools (gcc version 4.8.1 (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project)). Demonstrating Barry's answer, `NULL` is defined as `#define NULL __null` for this set-up.

Comment: I do not understand why you are saying "... it should show ambiguity with the below example, but it isn't !!"  What you ought to say is "...it may show ambiguity..." (depending on compiler and platform).

Comment: @RemyLebeau `(void*)0` would not have been standard compliant in c++. Only null pointer literals are allowed. It's valid In C though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As `NULL` can be casted into integral types, **it should show ambiguity** with the below example, but it isn't !!

The problem with `NULL`, which was one of the motivating reasons for introducing `nullptr`, is that you really cannot say how it **should** behave. There are numerous different ways that `NULL` can be defined, and depending on that choice of definition, you could have different behavior here - it could lead to either of the two functions behind called *or* being ambiguous. You can't say without knowing how your vendor defines that macro.

The nice thing about `nullptr` is that it will, without question, call the `int*` overload.

Answer (score 12):

In C++, `NULL` is defined as integral type. Your compiler probably defines it as `long`, since it matches that overload. C++ standard explicitly states *<sup>(draft N3936, page 444)</sup>*:

> Possible definitions [of macro NULL] include 0 and 0L, but not (void*)0.

This restriction is necessary, because e.g. `char *p = (void*)0` is valid C but invalid C++, whereas `char *p = 0` is valid in both.